# Possible to disable rack-cache on a per-request basis in Rails 3.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, streaming, rack

I have been attempting to get streaming working in Rails 3.2 on Heroku (see my SO post here: [Rails 3.2 streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9915704/rails-3-2-streaming)).

I am coming to the conclusion that rack-cache is causing the problem. Disabling it using `config.middleware.delete(Rack::Cache)` in production.rb seems to fix it. This, obviously, disables it for my entire app.

I only want it disabled for the one streaming request (which is on the admin side and will be used infrequently). Is this possible? It'd be a major bummer to lose caching for the sake of one small (but required) admin feature.

Thanks very much!!!

Edit: I have attempted setting the headers to not cache the action in question, but Rack::Cache is still causing the streaming to fail. Totally disabling it is the only solution I have found so far.

Comment: What really helped me in this question was actually just knowing that you could disable Rack::Cache using `config.middleware.delete("Rack::Cache")`. (P.S.: It needs quotes around Rack::Cache.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up not needing to disable Rack-cache. Just needed to add this `self.response.headers['Last-Modified'] = Time.now.ctime.to_s`
 to my response.

Answer (score 1):

While you can't disable it, you might not need to; you may just need to bypass the caching mechanism.

Per the source [here](https://github.com/rtomayko/rack-cache/blob/master/lib/rack/cache/context.rb#L65) and [here](https://github.com/rtomayko/rack-cache/blob/master/lib/rack/cache/request.rb#L28), if the `Cache-Control: no-cache` header or the `Pragma: no-cache` headers are set, Rack::Cache won't attempt to pull a request from the cache. That doesn't disable it, but it does let you ensure that you don't have a request that shouldn't be cached end up returning a caching response.

Additionally, you can ensure that Rack::Cache never caches a response for a given action with something like:

```
response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'private,max-age=0,must-revalidate,no-store'
```

in your controller action. This will ensure that Rack::Cache (and any other upstream proxies) don't cache the response, resulting in an always-fresh hit to your backend.

If this fails, then you're likely having issues due to the `forward` method in context.rb. There doesn't seem to be a way to bypass it, so you'd probably want to patch Rack::Cache to just invoke `#call` if a certain header is set.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that setting the headers doesn't fix it. Seems like I need to get Rack::Cache totally out of the way. I'll investigate your patch idea... any pointers on how I might do that? Thanks!

Comment: You should drop the max-age. From RFC2616: If a request includes the no-cache directive, it SHOULD NOT include min-fresh, max-stale, or max-age.

Comment: That portion of the RFC applies to the request header, not the response headers.