# Long polling/push events between rails and ruby client

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, push-notification, publish-subscribe, long-polling

I search for a suitable way to build a pub/sub service between a Rails app and multiple Ruby clients.

I tried faye and faye-rails so far, but they are are not suitable, as messages getting queued up and not delivered until the client which is listening to the certain channel is restarted.
Also I am not able to use a service like Pusher or PubNub.

Any recommendations?

Cheers
Martin

Comment: Are you looking for message queuing tool?

Comment: If you mean something like ActiveMQ: No. Rather something like long polling, websockets etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Rails 4 you may take a look at [ActionController::Live](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Live.html). Won't that be suitable for your needs?

```
class MyController < ActionController::Base
  include ActionController::Live

  def stream
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/event-stream'
    100.times {
      response.stream.write "hello world\n"
      sleep 1
    }
  rescue IOError
    # client disconneted
  ensure
    response.stream.close
  end
end
```

For earlier Rails you may give a try to this approach:
[Ruby on Rails 3: Streaming data through Rails to client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507594/ruby-on-rails-3-streaming-data-through-rails-to-client), 
[Rails 3.2 streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9915704/rails-3-2-streaming) (the 2nd link is to notice the `Last-Modified` header)

Comment: Unfortunately the project uses rails 3.2

Comment: I updated my answer with a couple of links, you may try to play with that approach